# Maven archetype:generate forcing groupId as package structure

Tags: maven, package, maven-archetype, archetypes

I'm trying to create an archetype to generate a Maven project with some properties that will be used in the files and with the file names and directory structure.

The problem I am running into is how to control the package directory structure? No matter what I have tried so far, the `groupId` I specify (which is a mandatory parameter in `archetype:generate`) forces itself as the package directory structure. If I try and have something different in my `archetype-resources` directory setup, or in the package name in the Java files themselves, I end up with whatever I specified there, AS WELL AS the `groupId`.

Effectively, I want my project structure to be different to my `groupId`, but the archetype generate seems to be forcing the `groupId` onto the package structure.

Is there a way to stop this?

If I use the following command:

```
archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=archetype.test -DarchetypeArtifactId=archetype-test -DarchetypeVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=com.example.test.project-DartifactId=my.test.project.artifact -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

With the following `fileset`:

```
<fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true">
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/MyClass.java</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
```

I end up with my Java files being under:

```
src/main/java/com/example/test/project/MyClass.java.
```

I still want the same `groupId`, but I want my class to be in a separate directory, such as:

```
src/main/java/com/different/project/MyClass.java
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Create a Project from an Archetype – Batch mode](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/generate.html#Batch_mode):

> It is possible to call the Archetype Plugin to generate a project in batch mode (to get rid of the prompting). This is achieved by providing the Archetype Plugin with all the needed values as system properties.
>
> - ...
> - `package` specifies the package for the sources of the generated project
> - ...

Long story short, add the following to your command line:

```
-Dpackage=com.different.project
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking at old documentation and trying -DpackageName. It seems that was replaced with -Dpackage and it works fine using that.

Comment: @James Off-topic SO usage hint (since it seems that you're not that active on SE sites): Do you know that you can show [additional appreciation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) by also upvoting an accepted answer?

Comment: Done. :) Thanks again!